# Why am I getting TypeError: string indices must be integers?

Tags: python, string, typeerror, argparse

I am very new to coding, and I am trying to write a piece of code to search a column in a csv file for a keyword. I do not understand why I am getting "TypeError: string indices must be integers" when I try to test the code that I have.

I don't really know what to try. I have tried changing the names of my variables, but this doesn't seem to help.

## Standard Libraries

import os
import pandas as pd
import argparse
import numpy as np

## Define arguments

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Takes a CSV file and searches a specified column a keyword")
parser.add_argument("--csv", dest="csv", action='store', required=True,help="Name of the CSV file [required]")
parser.add_argument("--kw", dest="keyword", action='store', required=True,help="Keyword being searched for")
parser.add_argument("--cl", dest="column_name", action='store', required=True, help= "Name of column that is being searched")
parser.add_argument("--ocl", dest='output_column_name', action='store', required=True, help="Name of column in ouput file")
parser.add_argument("--outdir", dest="odir" , action='store', required=True, help="Out directory path")
args=parser.parse_args()
```

## Standardized some paths before continue

```
file= args.csv
key = args.keyword
outColName= args.output_column_name
outdir= args.odir

print(key)

def gene_database_search(key, file):
    colName = 'flag_' + key
    file[colName] = np.where(file[args.column_name].str.contains(key), 1, 0)
    return file[[outColName,colName]]

keywordList = [key]

for key in keywordList:
    print(key)
    de = gene_database_search(key,file)
    de.to_csv(outdir/'flag_'+ key + '_list.csv')
```

I should get a csv file as output, but I get the TypeError on lines 35 and 42.

Comment: can you post the traceback? We can't see line numbers :P

Comment: In Python you have to pay attention to **what** various objects are.  You should choose names that give **you** some indication of the item is.  For example `filename=args.csv`, is a string, a filename, not a file.  To look for columns you have to first `open` and `load` the file.  I suspect you need to load the csv using `pandas`.  If so you need to import that and use the correct loader.

Answer (score 0):

`args.csv` is a string, which means `file` is too, but you're doing:

```py
file[colName] = np.where(file[args.column_name].str.contains(key), 1, 0)
```

What is it you're trying to do here?